# Show interstitial ad more than once

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

Please help. The interstitial ad is shown only once. I want it to be shown more.

```
private void loadAds() {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
    AdRequest adRequest2 = new AdRequest.Builder().build(); //
    interstitial.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.admob_interstitial));
    interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            AdLoaded = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            super.onAdClosed();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            AdLoaded = true;
        }
    });

    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest2);
}

public void displayInterstitial() {
    if (adsCounter == 0) {
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
            interstitial.show();
        }
        adsCounter = 0;
    } else {
        adsCounter += 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relpce `OnAdClosed()` with this

```
    @Override
          public void onAdClosed () 
          {
              AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .build();
              interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

After an interstitial has been shown, you need to call `loadAd(adRequest)` again in order to load a new interstitial.

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to call .destroy and make new instance.

Make global variable

```
private MoPubInterstitial interstitial;
```

place the boilerplate code in a function: createInterstitialAd.

```
 private void createInterstitialAd(){

        // TODO: Replace this test id with your personal ad unit id
        interstitial = new MoPubInterstitial(getActivity(), "<#YOUR_AD_UNIT_ID#>");
        interstitial.setInterstitialAdListener(this);
        interstitial.load();

    }
```

Then in the InterstitialAdListener methods where an ad fails to load or after it has loaded call (note: ***Also call this in the onCreateView***)

```
interstitial.destroy();
   createInterstitialAd();
```